# Share link for facebook not displaying my url

Tags: html, facebook

I want to have share icons on my page, each with a link to create a post, share, link to my site. Currently I am having problems with the facebook link.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.phpu=https://www.kocomo.com/homes/casa-las-tinajas" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="https://upload ssl.webflow.com/60e44a4909f0339510b4e01e/612fe315be44eb46cbdad9aa_facebook-icon.svg" class="share-icon face-btn"/></a>
```

Currently it says page not found, but if I take away the /casa-las-tinajas out it works. Any clue or idea?

[image]

Comment: Well It says it does not find the page

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.phpu=https://www.kocomo.com/homes/casa-las-tinajas
```

Try

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.kocomo.com/homes/casa-las-tinajas
```

I've added a `?` after `.php`